# Autogenerating control ids in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Ive noticed if I add a TextBox to to a page, without assigning it a ID property, then this property gets generated automatically in accordance with the control hierarchy of that rendered page.

I'm creating a custom control that is to be used multiple times on one page (so hardcoding an ID is not going to work).

Does ASP.NET have a method I can use to generate a 'unique' ID for each of these controls?

Comment: So you said if you don't hard code it ASP.NET will generate it. Why do you want to call a method then?

Comment: Are you deriving from any base control class?

Comment: can you explain why it won't work if it's used multiple times? depends on your `ClientIDMode`, multiple placements of your control may still end up with different unique IDs.

Answer (score 3):

You've sort of answered your own question - don't specify one and it will be generated for you.

Of interest might be [this post on Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) which describes the 'new' `ClientIdMode` available in ASP.NET 4:

> - **AutoID**—Renders the output as in .NET 3.5 (auto-generated IDs which will still render prefixes like ctrl00 for compatibility)
> - **Predictable (Default)**— Trims any “ctl00” ID string and if a list/container control concatenates child ids (example:
>     id=”ParentControl_ChildControl”)
> - **Static**—Hands over full ID naming control to the developer – whatever they set as the ID of the control is what is rendered
>     (example: id=”JustMyId”)
> - **Inherit**—Tells the control to defer to the naming behavior mode of the parent container control

Comment: "don't specify one and it will be generated for you."
Where/what is 'it' and how do I access it?

Comment: @maxp - I'm referring to the ClientId. Normally this is exposed and specified in the control's markup (`<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox"></asp:TextBox>`) rather than read-only in the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

you ARE able to override the `ClientID` or `UniqueID` if you want to. but using `ClientIDMode` is better.

```
public override string UniqueID
{
    get
    {
        return "newid";
    }
}

public override string ClientID
{
    get

    {
        return "newid";
    }
}
```